# What is the best practice for managing Application Specific Users in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Is there a "best practice" for managing application specific users for VMs in Google Cloud Platform? For example, in the old server world, you might have a "syslog" user for the syslog daemon, or an "nginx" user for nginx. In that world I would have created a "myapp" user for my application and then run the service under that user.

In the GCP world where we create VMs from stock images, the "myapp" user won't exist. Of course, I could create one and make a custom image, but I'm curious if there's a better (canonical GCP) way to do this.

This service does not need access to any Cloud APIs so service accounts don't immediately make sense to me. Plus, I'm not sure I could specify a service account as the user in my systemd unit file.

My goal is to allow the service to run under an unprivileged account on the VM. My question is: must I create this account using traditional unix tools, or is there a canonical GCP way? Or maybe this isn't done in the GCP world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is "[OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin)" feature in GCP:

> OS Login simplifies SSH access management by linking your Linux user
> account to your Google identity. Administrators can easily manage
> access to instances at either an instance or project level by setting
> IAM permissions.

In practice this works in a way that when an authorised user wants to log in to a VM, and he doesn't have an account there but a special tool (embedded in the OS image) detects that login attempt and creates an account for this user "on the fly" and then the user is authenticated. You can read more how this works in [How OS login works](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin#how_os_login_works) documentation. It's main goal is to manage users from the IAM page and not from the instances. That way you have central control over the users.

But it's not exactly the same as `syslog` type users you mentioned.

Here's also some documentation on [how to set up OS login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access).

There's no special (or canonical) way to manage unprivileged linux accounts (intended for running specific apps) so you have to do it the "old fashioned way".

GCP's VMs, despite being virtual, are regular linux based machines with users. Depending on your needs you may have to do this by hand. If your configuration is repeatable then create a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images).

Easier than a customer image is to create a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to create users when starting the VM. That approach has the upside of not having to create custom images, and will be *mostly* independent of the Linux flavour you run.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I amended my question with my goal. Happy to clarify further as needed, but I am just fishing a bit here, trying to get a handle on how things are done in GCP.

Comment: Gave you the check. I considered the startup script approach, or a custom image. Both seem reasonable given this is kinda old-school anyway.